# Limit of $f(x)^{g(x)}$, when $f(x)\to 0$ and $g(x)\to 0$

Tags: limits

I would like know real functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ for which the following is true:

1. $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are defined when $x \ge 0$
2. $\lim_{x \to 0^{+}} f(x)=0$ and $\lim_{x \to 0^{+}} g(x)=0$
3. $\lim_{x \to 0^{+}} f(x)^{g(x)}=a  \ne 1$

My textbook says that because of functions like this, $0^0$ is not $1$.
I think my textbook is wrong and such functions does not exist!
Because of (3), $f(x)^{g(x)}$ must be defined (and real) in some neighborhood of $0$, so ia $f(x)= \begin{cases}{} x\sin(1/x) \text{, if }x>0 \\ 0 \text{, if }x=0\end{cases}$ is not valid.

Until today, I thought that reason for not define $0^0$ is that also $0^0=0$ could be "good" definition, along the $0^0=1$. It can be both, so the best solution is not to define.

Comment: Take f(x) = 0 and g(x) = x

Comment: Or $f(x) = \exp(-1/x)$ and $g(x) = x$, which is what I got by "just doing it".

Comment: It is often convenient to DEFINE $0^0=1$ and this is often implicit. For example: "Let $f(x)=\sum_{j=0}^n a_jx^j$ be a real polynomial...."  What are we to make of the term $a_0x^0$ when $x=0$?

Answer (score 5):

There's plenty of such functions. I'll consider only $f$ positive, so let $\log f(x)=h(x)$. Your limit then becomes
$$
\lim_{x\to0^+}\exp(h(x)g(x))
$$
Note that you want $\lim_{x\to0^+}h(x)=-\infty$. A good choice is then
$$
g(x)=x, \qquad h(x)=-a/x \quad(a>0)
$$
for which $\lim_{x\to0}\exp(h(x)g(x))=e^{-a}$.

I'll leave to you finding examples where the limit is $\ge1$, $\infty$ or non existent.